# use of unresolved identifier FIRDynamicLinkComponents

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to create a firebase dynamic link, but I get error `use of unresolved identifier FIRDynamicLinkComponents`.  The frameworks I import in this viewcontroller are: Firebase and UIKit.
   FIRbaseDynamicLinks.framework screenshot attached below. 
What have I tried I tried?

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

Pod version: 1.5.2
Xcode Version 8.3.3
Swift 3

Terminal log when I run pod install

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies

Using Firebase (3.9.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.5.1)
Using FirebaseAuth (3.0.6)
Using FirebaseCore (3.4.4)
Using FirebaseDatabase (3.1.0)
Using FirebaseDynamicLinks (1.3.1)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.9)
Using FirebaseStorage (1.0.4)
Using FrameAccessor (1.3.2)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.1.15)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.4)

Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, the names are slightly different! To be more Swift-y, we alias the names for Swift without the "FIR" prefix. So `FIRDynamicLinkComponents` becomes [`DynamicLinkComponents`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedynamiclinks/api/reference/Classes/DynamicLinkComponents). This can be a bit confusing at time, though hopefully more readable overall!

To make life a little easier, we've now split our reference docs into [Swift](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedynamiclinks/api/reference/Classes/DynamicLinkComponents) and [Objective-C](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedynamiclinks/api/reference/Classes/FIRDynamicLinkComponents) versions, and generally have Swift and Objective-C tabs for all snippets in our guides.

Answer (score -1):

Import that pod file in Bridge header file of your project.

Comment: This is swift, not objective C

Comment: Yes but library you have post screen shot has .h file this is objective C file. So if you want to use that need to add in header file. @bibscy